# Can you restrict the access on a custom field type?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create a custom field type (MyCompLookup) that will be used in lists that all users will have access to. However, the field type will be fairly complicated / confusing to a regular user who is creating a simple list in their department's site. Is there a way to restrict certain users from selecting the custom field when they are creating columns for their lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't set ACL on field types.

A few things you can do to achieve some kind of workaround:

- Add a custom logic in SPField OnAdded method that removes the field immediately after it was added by a regular user. This method might be very confusing for users, so at least you should give a descriptive name to your field. You can find a similar solution [here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/creating-real-multi-column-fields-for-sharepoint/), where I add extra fields to the list in this method.
- You can add a custom editor control (see a simple sample [here](http://sharepoint.mindsharpblogs.com/NancyB/archive/2011/06/20/SharePoint-2010-Custom-Field-Types%5Bcoln%5D-Overview-and-Observations.aspx)) to your field, that interactsts with other controls on the add new field page, for example disables the OK button.

Hope it helps.